# Removing Weird Armor Textures/Objects on a Minecraft Model

Tags: texturing, objects

I really want to remove the armor texture after downloading a template, but I can't figure out how to remove the armor object and the armor texture! Please help me!

If you want to check out the file itself, click here: [Minecraft Blender Intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYDOx_e1Zt8)

[image]

Comment: Wondering what it looks like after rendering it, click here: [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYDOx_e1Zt8)

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the nature of your problem.  Is it that you cannot remove the armor, or do you not know how?

Comment: Please upload the .blend file so we can understand the construction of the model and textures.